# Disposable, one-time IMGs for drawImage

Tags: html, canvas, 2d, image, drawimage

When I `createElement("IMG")` solely for the purpose of using it in a 2d canvas using "`drawImage`", will the temporary IMG be eligible for a garbage collection? or will the canvas hold a reference to it (if so, how can I clear this reference)?

Answer (score 1):

It *ought to* be eligible for garbage collection, but of course each browser could (in theory) implement it differently.

If it is not eligible for garbage collection once you have cleared all references to it then that is a bug.

That being said, I imagine a lot of browsers hold on to the image in cache *anyway* so even if the Image object is garbage collected, making a new Image object with the same src may load instantly.

Comment: Since changing the SRC of an IMG causes any CANVAS that used it to update I believe that it is not marked of garbage disposable up until after the CANVAS is discarded